При подключении 2 игрока через Photon, мастер клиент не видит игрока, а игрок видит обоих


Пробовал создать новый проект и даже там все то же самое, один игрок видит себя, другой видит обоих.
Если подключиться 3 игрок, он будет видеть себя и мастер клиент, а 2 игрока-нет.
Из-за чего может возникнуть такой баг?

Проверь фотон вью, трансформ вью, проверь скрипт инициализации. Посмотри всегда ли приходит евент нового коннекта.

Все проверил, не работает, как уже и говорил, создавал новый проект и запихивал код от Emerald Powder, в точности, и он тоже не работает

Если кому-то понадобиться, то чтобы все это заработало, нужно удалить вот эту строку из подключения:         PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;

Удаление этой строки из подключения действительно помогло:
PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;

